# Avoid being assigned to a particular node in cluster

Tags: shell-script, cluster

I am using the department's cluster which adapts the pbs queuing system to run some mpi programs. Are there any ways that I can avoid being assigned to a particular node when submitting a job via qsub ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole point of a scheduler system is that it picks an appropriate host on which to run your job, only if your system administrator has declared some particular resource that you can request and which isn't available on the host which you want to avoid.

If such a thing isn't available, then I suspect that the difference between the host you want to avoid and the other hosts is unintentional.

In either case, I would suggest that you talk to your system administrator.

Comment: yes, only the local sysadmins can know how the cluster is set up, how the individual compute nodes are defined in the cluster config, and how to distinguish between nodes with/without particular features/resources.